# Pycparser not getting imported

Tags: python, pycparser

2.7.11 python pckg for Mac - and installed the same.

Now I am trying to execute a python file
**python file1.py**

It throws up the error :

---

> File "file1.py", line 107, in 
>       from pycparser import parse_file, c_parser, c_ast ImportError: No module named pycparser

---

How do I install this pycparser module ? can someone please help me here .

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. you need install pycparser.

```
pip install pycparser
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should go to File -> Settings -> Project: -> Project Interpreter and then on right hand side is a green plus and after clicking it add the "pycparser". Of course after instaling pycparser in cmd"pip3 install pycparser".